# Ansible Populate Template File with Dynamic Variables

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm having the following jinja template:

```
# Configure static IP for Ubuntu 22.04 machine
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - {{ item.new_static_ip }}/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [{{ item.netplan_name_servers }}] # Populate this list with the DNS servers necessary.
      renderer: networkd
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: {{ item.netplan_router_gateway }}
  version: 2
```

In my task, I have the following:

```
- name: Copy the template 00-installer-config.yaml over
  template:
    src: 00-netplan-static-ip-config-ubuntu.j2
    dest: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
    backup: yes
  with_items:
    - { new_static_ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}", netplan_name_servers: "1.1.1.1", netplan_router_gateway: "{{ router_gateway_address }}" }
```

I get an error like this:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'new_static_ip' is undefined
```

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Comment: The new_static_ip is passed as a dict so remove the item.new_static_ip and just use item

Comment: I cannot pass it in via arguments, because I will be running it against several hosts, so I need to pass it in like how I'm doing it in my code above.

Comment: What version of Ansible are you using? Your template task runs successfully when I try it, using Ansible core 2.14.1.

Comment: ansible [core 2.13.7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using vars like this:

```
# Set Static IP using netplan
- name: Copy the template 00-installer-config.yaml over
  vars:
    new_static_ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
    netplan_name_servers: "1.1.1.1"
    netplan_router_gateway: "{{ router_gateway_address }}"
  template:
    src: 00-netplan-static-ip-config-ubuntu.j2
    dest: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
    backup: yes
```